# Powershell -replace giving strange behaviour

Tags: regex, powershell

This is driving me nuts! Would appreciate any pointers as to what is going on, please!

```
$alpha = 'aaa.bbb.$connection.ccc.ddd'
$s = [regex]::match($alpha,"\$.+?(?=\.)").Value

"Alpha is: $alpha"
"Matched chunk is: $s"

$newChunk = "'" + $s + "'"
"New chunk is: $newChunk"

$beta = $alpha -replace $s,$newChunk
"Beta is: $beta"
```

This produces the following output:

```
Alpha is: aaa.bbb.$connection.ccc.ddd
Matched chunk is: $connection
New chunk is: '$connection'
Beta is: aaa.bbb.$connection.ccc.ddd
```

I am trying to identify/match character sequences in a path that begin with the literal '$' and continue until, but does not include a literal dot "." char. In the example code above the string would be "$connection".

Then I need to wrap that string in single quotes, so in the example above the $newChunk value would become '$connection' including the single quotes.

Next, I need to replace the matched value with the new single quoted value in the original string. No matter what I try (same with [regex]::match method too), the single quotes are stripped out. So, effectively, I am trying to turn:

```
aaa.bbb.$connection.ccc.ddd
```

into

```
aaa.bbb.'$connection'.ccc.ddd
```

Using Powershell 7.1 and would really appreciate someone telling me why this does not work. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the rich detail. Very helpful indeed! Yes, I thought that -replace would simply substitute string literals. It never occurred to me that the leading  $ might be interpreted. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
$beta = $alpha -replace '\$[^.]+', "'$&'"
```

See [proof](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%24%5B%5E.%5D%2B&i=aaabbb.%24connection.ccc.ddd&r=%27%24%26%27).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \$                       '$'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^.]+                    any character except: '.' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

The `$&` is the placeholder for the entire match.

Comment: Beautiful answer and gets me going again - thank you!
I would love to know why the original code didn't work if anyone knows?

Thanks Ryszard

Comment: @Indrid You used `$s`, holding `$connection`, that when used as a regex, matches the end of string followed with `connection`. This cannot happen. You would need to escape `$`, maybe using `[regex]::escape`. No need to do that though, `$&` is designed to be used in exactly cases like this.

Comment: Outstanding. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

**[Ryszard Czech's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64198630/45375) is definitely the best solution**: generically referring to what the ***regex-based* [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator)** matched, in its replacement operand, with **placeholder `$&`** is the simplest and most robust solution.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) for **other placeholders** you can use, such as what *preceded* (`` $` ``) or *succeeded* (`$'`) the match, or what a *capture group* matched (e.g. `$1`).

---

As for **what you tried**:

- Instead of using your regex `\$.+?(?=\.)` *directly* with the *regex-based* [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator), you used the *verbatim result* of an explicit `[regex].Match()` call as the search operand (first RHS operand) for `-replace`, which is then *again* interpreted as a regex.

  - However, **in order to use a string *verbatim* as the `-replace` *search* operand**, any **regex *metacharacters*** - i.e., characters with special syntactic meaning - **must be `\`-escaped**, such as the verbatim `$` in your string, which you can do with **[`[regex]::Escape($s)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape)**
- Additionally, you used a *replacement operand* that had an *embedded `$` char.* that you meant to be interpreted *verbatim*, but `$` in the replacement operand is a *metacharacter*, referring to *placeholders* such as `$&`.

  - **In order to use a string *verbatim* as the `-replace` *replacement* operand**, you must *programmatically* **escape embedded `$` chars. as `$$`**<sup>[1]</sup>:
    The simplest approach is to use the `[string]` type's literal-substring replacement method, `.Replace()`:

    ```
    $replacementOperand = '$foo'    
    'value is: (value)' -replace '\(value\)', $replacementOperand.Replace('$', '$$')
    ```

Thus, your original approach would have had to use the following command - but do note that Ryszard's solution is much simpler overall:

```
$beta = $alpha -replace [regex]::replace($s), $newChunk.Replace('$', '$$')
```

---

<sup>[1] *Situationally* you may get away without escaping, because a `$`-prefixed token that isn't recognized as a placeholder is left *untouched* (e.g., `'bar' -replace 'r', '$x'` behaves the same as `'bar' -replace 'r', '$$x'`), but the only *robust* solution is to escape verbatim `$` chars. by doubling them.</sup>