# Replace Vertical bar within a text file

Tags: powershell, replace

I am trying to replace a | character within a text file.  But I am not sure how to do it because the batch is not reading the |.

`powershell -Command "(gc output.txt) -replace '|', ' ' | Out-File -encoding ASCII output.txt"`

Which takes this input:
`80853||OHNED|Mira`

And outputs: `8 0 8 5 3 | | O H N E D | M i r a`

Where I'd like this output `80853  OHNED Mira`

Is there anyway within a batch to replace the | character?

Edit - While googling, I found out that the | character is called a vertical bar.

Comment: the pipe `|` is special character in regex and `-replace` is a regex compatible operator. preferable, since you want to replace a literal pipe, you should use a replacement method that replaces characters literally: `(gc output.txt -Raw).Replace('|', ' ') ....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>**Note**: This answer is in the context of using the PowerShell [*CLI*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) (`powershell -Command "..."`), but in essence equally applies to code in PowerShell scripts (`*.ps1`) and functions.

An alternative to `\`-escaping is a regex *character set* (`[...]`), which also allows you to match *multiple* characters; e.g. `'a|b&c' -replace '[|&]'` -> `'abc'`</sup>

Alternatively, use a regex character set (`[...]`): `Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '[?|!&]' }`

**PowerShell's `-replace` operator is [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based**; since your intent is to replace all `|` characters *verbatim*, you must ***escape* `|` as `\|`**, given that `|` is a regex *metacharacter* (a character with special meaning in the context of a regex (regular expression)):

```
powershell -Command "(gc output.txt) -replace '\|', ' ' | Out-File -encoding ASCII output.txt"
```

In cases where escaping individual characters isn't an option or would be cumbersome - e.g. if you're *given* a search string that you want to treat literally, *as a whole* - use [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape):

```
powershell -Command "(gc output.txt) -replace [regex]::Escape('|'), ' ' | Out-File -encoding ASCII output.txt"
```

---

**Alternatively**, in your simple case you could use the **`.Replace()` string *method***, which invariably **performs *verbatim* replacements** and therefore does *not* require escaping:

```
powershell -Command "(gc output.txt).Replace('|', ' ') | Out-File -encoding ASCII output.txt"
```

Note:

- Unlike PowerShell's operators, the `[string]` type's [`.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Replace) method is case-*sensitive*, *invariably* so in Windows PowerShell, and *by default* in PowerShell (Core) 6+.

---

See also:

- For **general guidance on when to use PowerShell's `-replace` operator vs. the .NET `[string]` type's `.Replace()` method**, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64771432/45375).
- For **robustly escaping *all* metacharacters in a `-replace` search regex and/or in its replacement operand** in order to treat one or both as *verbatim* strings, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64200264/45375).

Answer (score 2):

Edit : This can did the trick to replace the special char :

```
@echo off
powershell -Command "(gc input.txt -raw) -replace '([\^&<>\|\(\)!])', ' ' | Out-File output.txt"
start "" output.txt
```

Comment: That basically takes the input of ```80853||OHNED|Mira``` and outputs the same thing ```80853||OHNED|Mira```

Comment: Check my last edit

Comment: Only `|` needs escaping in this case. If you need to treat the search operand _generally_ as a verbatim string, use `[regex]::Escape()`.